# 2195 port is compulsory require to open? IOS Push notification not working in php and Ios Push notification not comming into mobile in laravel

Tags: php, swift, laravel, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push notification using php code and ios didn't get notification so whats the exact issue i don't know please help.

```
public static function ios_push($device_token,$title,$msg,$description,$type = "",$r_type = "")
{
    \Log::info('device_token', ['context' => $device_token]);
    \Log::info($device_token);

    $badge_count =2;
    $streamContext = stream_context_create();

    $connectTimeout = 60;

    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase',IPHONE_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD);

    \Log::info(IPHONE_CERTIFICATE_TYPE);

    if(IPHONE_CERTIFICATE_TYPE == "Development") 

    {

      //For Development

      stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert',IOS_PUSH_DEV_PEM_PATH);

      $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, $connectTimeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT |STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);

    } 

    else 

    {

      //For Production 

      stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert',WWW_ROOT_PATH.IOS_PUSH_DEV_PEM_PATH);

      $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, $connectTimeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT |STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);

    }

    if (!$apns) {
        \Log::info('Error : '.$error.' '.$errorString);
    } else {
        \Log::info("success");
    }

    $music = 'default';

    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => ['title'=>$title,'body'=>$msg], 'badge' => $badge_count,'title'=>$description,'sound'=> $music , 'notification_type' =>  $type);

    //$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => "vikas", 'badge' => $badge_count,'sound'=> $music , 'notification_type' =>  $type);

    // $data['notification_type'] = $notification_type;

    // $data['sender_first_name'] = $sender_first_name;

    // $data['sender_last_name'] = $sender_last_name;

    // $data['sender_user_id'] = $sender_user_id;

    $data['sound'] = $music;

    $data['title'] = $title;

    $data['notification_type'] = $type;

    $data['report_type'] = !empty($r_type) ? substr($r_type, 0, -8) : "";

    $payload['data'] = $data;



    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    \Log::info('Log message', ['payload' => json_encode($payload)]);



    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*',  $device_token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload; 

    $fwriteRes = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage, strlen($apnsMessage));     

    fclose($apns);

    return true;

}
```

This is my function

But IOS didn't get any notification in mobile

SO whats the issue

**The issue for 2195 port is close thats why?**

Comment: YES !!!! I GOT THE SOLUTION!! YEHEE

Comment: Below I put the answer of my question please refer this answer If any one not getting ios push notification or getting error in ios push notification.

Comment: IOS push notification old code is change thats why notiication will be stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is perfectly help for me!!!!

**-----------==>  Step 1**

***First of all you need to install this composer library.***

```
compose require lcobucci/jwt:^3.3.1
```

**-----------==>  Step 2**

***Then write code like..***

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Ecdsa\Sha256; 

public static function generateiosauthtoken() {
    $key = file_get_contents('Your p8 file');  // p8 file
    $signer = new Sha256();
    $time = time();
    return  (new Builder())->issuedBy("TEAMID") // iss claim
            ->permittedFor('https://appleid.apple.com') // aud claim
            ->expiresAt($time + 3600) // exp claim
            ->issuedAt($time) // iat claim
            ->withHeader('kid', "KEYID") // kid header
            ->getToken($signer, new Key($key));
}


public static function ios_push($device_token,$title,$msg,$description)
{
    $token = ApiHelper::generateiosauthtoken();
    $music = 'default';
    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => ['title'=>$title,'body'=>$msg], 'badge' => 1,'title'=>$description,'sound'=> $music , 'notification_type' =>  $type);
    $data['sound'] = $music;
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $payload['data'] = $data;
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP09_ALLOWED, true);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_PORT => "443",
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device/".$device_token."",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "apns-topic: bundleid", // put it here your aplication bundle id
        "authorization: bearer ".$token."",
       
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
      $arr = array("code" => 400, "msg" => $err,"flag" => false , "data" => (object)array());
      \Response::json($arr);
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add lcobucci/jwt to a shared website with just file access?

Comment: you need to install `compose require lcobucci/jwt:^3.3.1` library.

Answer (score 1):

I think port 443 is used now

[Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc)

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools?language=objc

I've been talking to Apple via the developer portal and so far this is all I know. I've now decided to just cherry pick and see what other devs that use APNS did to keep the deliveries successful. I asked this question too and now that I'm browsing the Apple-Push-Notifications tag, I see others are too.

Comment: So i can use this url like ssl://api.push.apple.com:443 ?

Comment: for connectionn

Comment: Hey @VikasKatariya I'm still troubleshooting with Apple. I'm not entirely sure, I just now that anything with port 2195 is completely deprecated.

Comment: Hey @VikasKatariya here is what Apple told me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911

Comment: currently i have not getting any solution

Comment: Trying a certificate or token based connection? I will be testing it out later today. Update in progress...Thanks for the response.

Comment: I could honestly be wrong about the PEM aspect. I didn't see it mentioned anywhere. I will take another look.

Comment: Update: I was wrong about the PEM aspect. Creating a PEM file is still necessary for APNs connections using the new APNs Provider API.